# Scala: How to make case class copy keep manifest information

Tags: scala, manifest, type-erasure, type-parameter

A case classes `copy()` method is supposed to make an identical copy of the instance, plus replacing any fields by name. This seems to fail when the case class has type parameters with manifests. The copy loses all knowledge of the types of its parameters.

```
case class Foo[+A : Manifest](a: A) {
  // Capture manifest so we can observe it
  // A demonstration with collect would work equally well
  def myManifest = implicitly[Manifest[_ <: A]]
}

case class Bar[A <: Foo[Any]](foo: A) {
  // A simple copy of foo
  def fooCopy = foo.copy()
}

val foo = Foo(1)
val bar = Bar(foo)

println(bar.foo.myManifest)     // Prints "Int"
println(bar.fooCopy.myManifest) // Prints "Any"
```

Why does `Foo.copy` lose the manifest on the parameters and how do I make it retain it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Several Scala peculiarities interact to give this behavior. The first thing is that `Manifest`s are not only appended to the secret implicit parameter list on the constructor but also on the copy method. It is well known that

`case class Foo[+A : Manifest](a: A)`

is just syntactic sugar for

`case class Foo[+A](a: A)(implicit m: Manifest[A])`

but this also affects the copy constructor, which would look like this

`def copy[B](a: B = a)(implicit m: Manifest[B]) = Foo[B](a)(m)`

All those `implicit m`s are created by the compiler and sent to the method through the implicit parameter list.

This would be fine as long as one was using the `copy` method in a place where the compiler knew `Foo`s type parameter. For example, this will work outside of the Bar class:

```
val foo = Foo(1)
val aCopy = foo.copy()
println(aCopy.myManifest) // Prints "Int"
```

This works because the compiler infers that `foo` is a `Foo[Int]` so it knows that `foo.a` is an `Int` so it can call `copy` like this:

`val aCopy = foo.copy()(manifest[Int]())`

(Note that `manifest[T]()` is a function that creates a manifest representation of the type `T`, e.g. `Manifest[T]` with a capital "M". Not shown is the addition of the default parameter into `copy`.) It also works within the `Foo` class because it already has the manifest that was passed in when the class was created. It would look something like this:

```
case class Foo[+A : Manifest](a: A) {
  def myManifest = implicitly[Manifest[_ <: A]]

  def localCopy = copy()
}

val foo = Foo(1)
println(foo.localCopy.myManifest) // Prints "Int"
```

In the original example, however, it fails in the `Bar` class because of the second peculiarity: while the type parameters of `Bar` are known within the `Bar` class, the type parameters of the type parameters are not. It knows that `A` in `Bar` is a `Foo` or a `SubFoo` or `SubSubFoo`, but not if it is a `Foo[Int]` or a `Foo[String]`. This is, of course, the well-known type erasure problem in Scala, but it appears as a problem here even when it doesn't seem like the class is doing anything with the type of `foo`s type parameter. But it is, remember there is a secret injection of a manifest every time `copy` is called, and those manifests overwrite the ones that were there before. Since the `Bar` class has no idea was the type parameter of `foo` is, it just creates a manifest of `Any` and sends that along like this:

`def fooCopy = foo.copy()(manifest[Any])`

If one has control over the `Foo` class (e.g. it's not `List`) then one workaround it by doing all the copying over in the Foo class by adding a method that will do the proper copying, like `localCopy` above, and return the result:

```
case class Bar[A <: Foo[Any]](foo: A) {
  //def fooCopy = foo.copy()
  def fooCopy = foo.localCopy
}

val bar = Bar(Foo(1))
println(bar.fooCopy.myManifest) // Prints "Int"
```

Another solution is to add `Foo`s type parameter as a manifested type parameter of `Bar`:

```
case class Bar[A <: Foo[B], B : Manifest](foo: A) {
  def fooCopy = foo.copy()
}
```

But this scales poorly if class hierarchy is large, (i.e. more members have type parameters, and those classes also have type parameters) since every class would have to have the type parameters of every class below it. It also seems to make the type inference freak out when trying to construct a `Bar`:

```
val bar = Bar(Foo(1)) // Does not compile

val bar = Bar[Foo[Int], Int](Foo(1)) // Compiles
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems as you identified.  The first problem is the type erasure problem inside of `Bar`, where `Bar` doesn't know the type of `Foo`'s manifest.   I would personally use the `localCopy` workaround you suggested.

The second issue is that another implicit is being secretly injected into `copy`.  That issue is resolved by explicitly passing the value again into the `copy`.  For example:

```
scala> case class Foo[+A](a: A)(implicit val m: Manifest[A @uncheckedVariance])
defined class Foo

scala> case class Bar[A <: Foo[Any]](foo: A) {
     | def fooCopy = foo.copy()(foo.m)
     | }
defined class Bar

scala> val foo = Foo(1)
foo: Foo[Int] = Foo(1)

scala> val bar = Bar(foo)
bar: Bar[Foo[Int]] = Bar(Foo(1))

scala> bar.fooCopy.m
res2: Manifest[Any] = Int
```

We see the copy has kept the `Int` manifest but the type of `fooCopy` and `res2` is `Manifest[Any]` due to erasure.

Because I needed access to the implicit evidence to do the `copy` I had to use the explicit `implicit` (hah) syntax instead of the context bound syntax.  But using the explicit syntax caused errors:

```
scala> case class Foo[+A](a: A)(implicit val m: Manifest[A])
<console>:7: error: covariant type A occurs in invariant position in type => Manifest[A] of value m
       case class Foo[+A](a: A)(implicit val m: Manifest[A])
                                         ^
scala> case class Foo[+A](a: A)(implicit val m: Manifest[_ <: A])
defined class Foo

scala> val foo = Foo(1)
<console>:9: error: No Manifest available for Int.
```

WTF?  How come the context bound syntax works and the explicit `implicit` doesn't?  I dug around and found a solution to the problem: the `@uncheckedVariance` annotation.

**UPDATE**

I dug around some more and found that in Scala 2.10 case classes have been changed to *only* copy the fields from the first parameter list in `copy()`.

> Martin says: case class ness is only bestowed on the first argument
>   list the rest should not be copied.

See the details of this change at https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5009.

Comment: I was trying to do this but didn't know about `@uncheckedVariance`. Can that lead to some unsound assignments, or is the need for it just an artifact of the fact that there aren't separate covariant and contravariant `Manifest`s in Scala?

Comment: I think it's just an artifact. I was frustrated that the context bound syntax worked, but the explicit implicit syntax didn't, so I dug around and found `@uncheckedVariance`.  My guess is that the context bound syntax is basically doing `@uncheckedVariance` behind the scenes.

Comment: Added info on `@uncheckedVariance` to the answer.

Comment: Added info on relevant changes in Scala 2.10